# Dynamically change text

Tags: jquery, html

Is it possible to dynamically change the ordering in this HTML ?

```
<li><a href="#step-4">
  <label class="stepNumber">4</label>
  <span class="stepDesc">
     Finish<br />
     <small>LAST STEP</small>
  </span>                   
</a></li>
```

I have a button with id 'finish' that when clicked will submit some data via ajax. Once this is done, I'd like to change the above words:

Finish should become finished
LAST STEP should be come completed.

Any way I can do this ?

Thanks

```
$('#finish').click(function() {

});
```

Comment: on your jqXHR chain `.success(function(){ $('#step-4 small').text('COMPLETED'); })` should work perfectly

Answer (score 11):

Your ajax success would be as below:

```
$('#finish').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
         ...
         ...
         success:function(data)
         {
             $('span.stepDesc').text('Finished');
             $('span.stepDesc small').text('Completed');

         }
     });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#finish').on('click',function(event) {
       $('.stepDesc')[0].innerHTML = 'Finished<br /><small>COMPLETED</small>'
   });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><a href="#step-4">
  <label class="stepNumber">4</label>
  <span class="stepDesc">
     Finish<br />
     <small>LAST STEP</small>
  </span>                   
</a></li>

<button id="finish">Finish</button>
```

And just for future reference. If it's only to change text use `text()` instead of `innerHTML` due to performance. So probably any other answer here using `text()` is better in performance compared to mine, but I'll let mine stay here for diversity.

Answer (score 3):

I  guess you can use:

```js
$("#finish").click(function() {
 $("#step").text("COMPLETED");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="finish"> Finish </button>
<li><a href="#step-4">
  <label class="stepNumber">4</label>
  <span class="stepDesc">
     Finish<br />
     <small id="step">LAST STEP</small>
  </span>                   
  </a></li>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the `text` to `finished` and then append the `small` tag.This would help -

```
$('#finish').click(function() {
   $('span.stepDesc').text('Finished').append('<br><small>Completed</small>');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#finish').click(function() {
  $('.stepNumber .stepDesc').html('Finished<br/><small>completed</small>');
});
```

Hope this works..

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying this?

```
$('#finish').click(function() {
   $('.stepDesc small').text('Completed')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#finish').click(function() {
$('.stepDesc').html('Finished<br /><small>COMPLETED</small>')
});
```